# Newcommand that uncludes a foreach with unknown number of parameters

Tags: macros, foreach, parameters

Sorry, but part of the code is in French. However, it won't matter because it's only the listed text

I currently have a new command named `\listerfe` that, combined with `\listerfenextarg` and `\listerfegobblenextarg`, succesfully proceeds an unknown number of parameters to separe them with a `,`

Now, I have this code:

```
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% !TeX spellcheck = fr_FR


\documentclass[utf8]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\foreachlinedo}[2]{\foreach \noeud in {\listerfe#1} {\draw[<-] (#2.east) -| ++(-1em,0em) |- (\noeud.west);}}

\newcommand{\listerfe}[1]{#1\listerfenextarg}
\newcommand{\listerfenextarg}{\@ifnextchar\bgroup{\listerfegobblenextarg}{}}
\newcommand{\listerfegobblenextarg}[1]{,#1\@ifnextchar\bgroup{\listerfegobblenextarg}{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \definecolor{couleurbackintr}{HTML}{7F00FF}
    \definecolor{couleurtextintr}{HTML}{FFFFFF}
    \definecolor{couleurbackfonc}{HTML}{C780FF}
    \definecolor{couleurtext}{HTML}{000000}
    \definecolor{couleurbackextr}{HTML}{DDB3FF}
    \begin{figure}[htp]
        \centering
        \tikzset{
            basic/.style={draw, rounded corners=2pt, thick, text width=8em, align=flush center, text=couleurtext, node distance=2em},
            intrant/.style={basic, fill=couleurbackintr, text=couleurtextintr},
            fonction/.style={basic, fill=couleurbackfonc},
            extrant/.style={basic, fill=couleurbackextr}
        }
        \begin{tikzpicture}[]
        \fontsize{8}{9} \selectfont
        % intrants
        \matrix[row sep=2em, column sep=2em] {
            % 1re ligne
            %TODO changer nom
            \node[intrant](forcutil){Force utilisée}; & \node[fonction](instcapt){Installer capteur sous l'eau}; & & & \node[extrant](captinst){Capteur installé}; \\
            % 2me ligne
            \node[intrant](defailla){Défaillance}; & \node[fonction](detcdefa){Détecter défaillance}; & & \node[fonction](genralrm){Générer alarme}; & \node[extrant](alarme){Alarme}; \\
            \node[intrant](poissons){Poissons}; & \node[fonction](detecteu){Détecteur}; & \node[fonction](photo){Photo}; & \node[fonction](accudonn){Accumuler données}; & \\
            \node[intrant](elecbatt){Électicité batterie}; & \node[fonction](alimcapt){Alimenter capteur}; & & \node[fonction](idenpois){Identifier poisson}; & \\
            \node[intrant](tempreau){Température de l'eau}; & \node[fonction](captteau){Capteur température eau}; & & \node[fonction](archdonn){Archiver donnéees}; & \node[extrant](donnarch){Données archivées}; \\
            \node[intrant](tempintr){Température interne}; & \node[fonction](capttcpt){Capteur température interne}; & & & \\
            \node[intrant](confvolm){Configuration volume}; & \node[fonction](confcapt){Configurer capteur}; & & & \\
            \node[intrant](entrutil){Entrées utilisateurs}; & \node[fonction](authutil){Authentifier utilisateur}; & \node[fonction](accedonn){Accéder aux données}; & & \\
        };
        \foreachlinedo{{forcutil}{defailla}{poissons}}{instcapt};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Diagramme fonctionnel}
        \label{f:caf_diag_fonc}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Without the `\foreachlinedo`, so without arrows, it looks like this:

[image]

Now, when I run this code, it tells me this:

```
Argument of \XC@definec@lor has an extra }. ...{{forcutil}{defailla}{poissons}}{instcapt}
Paragraph ended before \XC@definec@lor was complete. ...{{forcutil}{defailla}{poissons}}{instcapt}
Paragraph ended before \tikz@@scan@@no@calculator was complete. ...{{forcutil}{defailla}{poissons}}{instcapt}
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. \end{tikzpicture}
Missing } inserted. \end{tikzpicture}
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. \end{tikzpicture}
Missing } inserted. \end{tikzpicture}
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. \end{figure}
\begin{figure} on input line 30 ended by \end{document}. \end{document}
You can't use `\end' in internal vertical mode. \end{document}
\begin{figure} on input line 30 ended by \end{document}. \end{document}
Missing } inserted. \end{document}
Emergency stop.
Unused global option(s): [utf8]. % doesn't matter
```

I created `\foreachlinedo` because I don't want to create lots of `\foreach`, because there will be lots and lots of arrows combined inthe diagram.

How can I make it work?

Comment: Please don't get me wrong but all these efforts only because you do not want to write `\foreachlinedo{forcutil,defailla,poissons}{instcapt};`, which would allow you to have a very simple loop? Do you think that is worth it?

Comment: That can work. I'll try it. Edit: It works

Answer (score 1):

Working code:

```
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% !TeX spellcheck = fr_FR


\documentclass[utf8]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\foreachlinedo}[2]{\foreach \noeud in {#1} {\draw[<-] (#2.east) -| ++(-1em,0em) |- (\noeud.west);}}

\begin{document}

    \definecolor{couleurbackintr}{HTML}{7F00FF}
    \definecolor{couleurtextintr}{HTML}{FFFFFF}
    \definecolor{couleurbackfonc}{HTML}{C780FF}
    \definecolor{couleurtext}{HTML}{000000}
    \definecolor{couleurbackextr}{HTML}{DDB3FF}
    \begin{figure}[htp]
        \centering
        \tikzset{
            basic/.style={draw, rounded corners=2pt, thick, text width=8em, align=flush center, text=couleurtext, node distance=2em},
            intrant/.style={basic, fill=couleurbackintr, text=couleurtextintr},
            fonction/.style={basic, fill=couleurbackfonc},
            extrant/.style={basic, fill=couleurbackextr}
        }
        \begin{tikzpicture}[]
        \fontsize{8}{9} \selectfont
        % intrants
        \matrix[row sep=2em, column sep=2em] {
            % 1re ligne
            %TODO changer nom
            \node[intrant](forcutil){Force utilisée}; & \node[fonction](instcapt){Installer capteur sous l'eau}; & & & \node[extrant](captinst){Capteur installé}; \\
            % 2me ligne
            \node[intrant](defailla){Défaillance}; & \node[fonction](detcdefa){Détecter défaillance}; & & \node[fonction](genralrm){Générer alarme}; & \node[extrant](alarme){Alarme}; \\
            \node[intrant](poissons){Poissons}; & \node[fonction](detecteu){Détecteur}; & \node[fonction](photo){Photo}; & \node[fonction](accudonn){Accumuler données}; & \\
            \node[intrant](elecbatt){Électicité batterie}; & \node[fonction](alimcapt){Alimenter capteur}; & & \node[fonction](idenpois){Identifier poisson}; & \\
            \node[intrant](tempreau){Température de l'eau}; & \node[fonction](captteau){Capteur température eau}; & & \node[fonction](archdonn){Archiver donnéees}; & \node[extrant](donnarch){Données archivées}; \\
            \node[intrant](tempintr){Température interne}; & \node[fonction](capttcpt){Capteur température interne}; & & & \\
            \node[intrant](confvolm){Configuration volume}; & \node[fonction](confcapt){Configurer capteur}; & & & \\
            \node[intrant](entrutil){Entrées utilisateurs}; & \node[fonction](authutil){Authentifier utilisateur}; & \node[fonction](accedonn){Accéder aux données}; & & \\
        };
        \foreachlinedo{forcutil,defailla,poissons}{instcapt};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Diagramme fonctionnel}
        \label{f:caf_diag_fonc}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I don't need to parse multiple arguments, I just need to provide the list.

Comment: Please for a valid answer add an compilable tex code showing your solution and explain what you did. I guess this should be an answer, not an edit of your question? Have you considered to ask the author of the comment (that gave you the answer) to answer? He should earn the reputation ...